# Your Cassandra cluster failed to deploy. Replica State changed to PERMANENTLY_FAILING. Replica was unhealthy 2 consecutive times

Tags: cassandra, cluster-computing, google-compute-engine

I tried to deploy a Cassandra Cluster using Google Compute Engine, no success. I tried several times, the error was always the same:

```
module: DEPLOYMENT_FAILED
Replica module-1234 failed with status PERMANENTLY_FAILING: Replica State
changed to PERMANENTLY_FAILING. Replica was unhealthy 2 consecutive times.
```

After following this short troubleshooting guidelines: https://cloud.google.com/solutions/cassandra/click-to-deploy#troubleshooting, the log is the following:

```
antoniogallo88_gmail_com@cassandra-coord-v8ip:/gagent/metaOutput$ tail $(ls -1tr /gagent/metaOutput/stderr.*.txt | 
tail -n 1)
Still waiting for resourceview cassandranode-4da4e to have 3 members ...
Still waiting for resourceview cassandranode-4da4e to have 3 members ...
Still waiting for resourceview cassandranode-4da4e to have 3 members ...
Still waiting for resourceview cassandranode-4da4e to have 3 members ...
Still waiting for resourceview cassandranode-4da4e to have 3 members ...
Still waiting for resourceview cassandranode-4da4e to have 3 members ...
Still waiting for resourceview cassandranode-4da4e to have 3 members ...
Still waiting for resourceview cassandranode-4da4e to have 3 members ...
Still waiting for resourceview cassandranode-4da4e to have 3 members ...
[ERROR] resourceview cassandranode-4da4e does not have 3 members after 60 attempts.
```

Do you have any idea how to fix this?

Thanks.

Antonio

Answer (score 1):

Can you check that the instance type you've chosen (in # of cores) and the number of cluster members exceed the cpu quota for the project you're using?  Also check the disk capacity value and your overall disk quota.

You can check max allowable disk and CPU quota in the console under Compute Engine > Quotas.

This sounds like a quota issue even though the console is not surfacing a quota error.

Another thing you can do is create another deployment, then quickly switch over to the instance list page and look for an instance called "Cassandra-coord-foo" which is a short-lived instance that manages disk creation.  If you ssh into that node during deployment and run the following command, you may see a disk or CPU quota warning:

```
tail -f /gagent/metaOutput/*
```

Chris

Comment: I thought about this some more and its most likely related to CPU quota and not disk quota.  Check that the CPU quota is sufficient in the zone you're deploying to.

The Cassandra default, with n1-highmem-4 instance types needs 3*4 + 1 = 13 cores.  If you're using the free tier coupon, then I think you only gets 8 cores by default.  The default when you sign up using a billing method is 16 cores.  Most of of the click to deploy default configurations use this 16 core quota as a guideline.

Comment: I had the same issue and it looks like quota on in-use IP addresses has the same effect.