# Error while deploying second elastic search node to gcloud

Tags: elasticsearch, google-compute-engine

I have one ES node already running on google cloud. I tried deploying one more node in the same zone. But getting following error:

```
deploymentCoordinator: DEPLOYED
elasticsearchNode: DEPLOYMENT_FAILED
Replica elasticsearch2-elasticsearch-aidd failed with status PERMANENTLY_FAILING: Replica State changed to PERMANENTLY_FAILING. Replica was unhealthy 2 consecutive times.
```

According the [troubleshooting guide](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/elasticsearch/click-to-deploy) it not a quota problem. Though just to be sure I checked the complete quota page. Nowhere I am reaching limit.

The output of the `/gagent/metaOutput` logs is:

```
cat /gagent/metaOutput/stderr.4.txt
+++ cmdfunc48ec81cdc3035833d37ee18a066dd74543212f52
+++ cat
+++ /bin/bash elasticsearch_setup.sh
safe_format_and_mount: Running: fsck.ext4 -a /dev/disk/by-id/google-elasticsearch2-elasticsearch-aidd-data
safe_format_and_mount: fsck.ext4: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/disk/by-id/google-elasticsearch2-elasticsearch-aidd-data
safe_format_and_mount: /dev/disk/by-id/google-elasticsearch2-elasticsearch-aidd-data: 
safe_format_and_mount: The superblock could not be read or does not describe a correct ext2
safe_format_and_mount: filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2
safe_format_and_mount: filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
safe_format_and_mount: is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
safe_format_and_mount:     e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
safe_format_and_mount: 
safe_format_and_mount: Fsck could not correct errors on /dev/disk/by-id/google-elasticsearch2-elasticsearch-aidd-data
safe_format_and_mount: Running: mount -o discard,defaults /dev/disk/by-id/google-elasticsearch2-elasticsearch-aidd-data /elasticsearch
safe_format_and_mount: mount: you must specify the filesystem type
safe_format_and_mount: Running: mkfs.ext4 -F /dev/disk/by-id/google-elasticsearch2-elasticsearch-aidd-data
safe_format_and_mount: mke2fs 1.42.5 (29-Jul-2012)
safe_format_and_mount: Discarding device blocks: done                            
safe_format_and_mount: Filesystem label=
safe_format_and_mount: OS type: Linux
safe_format_and_mount: Block size=4096 (log=2)
safe_format_and_mount: Fragment size=4096 (log=2)
safe_format_and_mount: Stride=0 blocks, Stripe width=0 blocks
safe_format_and_mount: 1310720 inodes, 5242880 blocks
safe_format_and_mount: 262144 blocks (5.00%) reserved for the super user
safe_format_and_mount: First data block=0
safe_format_and_mount: Maximum filesystem blocks=4294967296
safe_format_and_mount: 160 block groups
safe_format_and_mount: 32768 blocks per group, 32768 fragments per group
safe_format_and_mount: 8192 inodes per group
safe_format_and_mount: Superblock backups stored on blocks: 
safe_format_and_mount:  32768, 98304, 163840, 229376, 294912, 819200, 884736, 1605632, 2654208, 
safe_format_and_mount:  4096000
safe_format_and_mount: 
safe_format_and_mount: Allocating group tables:  71/160
safe_format_and_mou144/160
safe_format_and_modone                            
safe_format_and_mount: Writing inode tables:  71/160
safe_format_and_144/160
safe_format_and_mdone                            
safe_format_and_mount: Creating journal (32768 blocks): done
safe_format_and_mount: Writing superblocks and filesystem accounting information:  68/160
safe_format_and_mount141/160
safe_format_and_mount:done   
safe_format_and_mount: 
safe_format_and_mount: Running: mount -o discard,defaults /dev/disk/by-id/google-elasticsearch2-elasticsearch-aidd-data /elasticsearch
Still waiting for resourceview elasticsearchnode-f18a8 to have 1 members ...
Still waiting for resourceview elasticsearchnode-f18a8 to have 1 members ...
Still waiting for resourceview elasticsearchnode-f18a8 to have 1 members ...
Still waiting for resourceview elasticsearchnode-f18a8 to have 1 members ...
Still waiting for resourceview elasticsearchnode-f18a8 to have 1 members ...
Still waiting for resourceview elasticsearchnode-f18a8 to have 1 members ...
Still waiting for resourceview elasticsearchnode-f18a8 to have 1 members ...
Still waiting for resourceview elasticsearchnode-f18a8 to have 1 members ...
Still waiting for resourceview elasticsearchnode-f18a8 to have 1 members ...
Still waiting for resourceview elasticsearchnode-f18a8 to have 1 members ...
Still waiting for resourceview elasticsearchnode-f18a8 to have 1 members ...
Still waiting for resourceview elasticsearchnode-f18a8 to have 1 members ...
Still waiting for resourceview elasticsearchnode-f18a8 to have 1 members ...
Still waiting for resourceview elasticsearchnode-f18a8 to have 1 members ...
Still waiting for resourceview elasticsearchnode-f18a8 to have 1 members ...
Still waiting for resourceview elasticsearchnode-f18a8 to have 1 members ...
safe_format_and_mount: Fsck could not correct errors on /dev/disk/by-id/google-elasticsearch2-elasticsearch-aidd-da
Still waiting for resourceview elasticsearchnode-f18a8 to have 1 members ...
Still waiting for resourceview elasticsearchnode-f18a8 to have 1 members ...
Still waiting for resourceview elasticsearchnode-f18a8 to have 1 members ...
Still waiting for resourceview elasticsearchnode-f18a8 to have 1 members ...
Still waiting for resourceview elasticsearchnode-f18a8 to have 1 members ...
Still waiting for resourceview elasticsearchnode-f18a8 to have 1 members ...
Still waiting for resourceview elasticsearchnode-f18a8 to have 1 members ...
Still waiting for resourceview elasticsearchnode-f18a8 to have 1 members ...
Still waiting for resourceview elasticsearchnode-f18a8 to have 1 members ...
Still waiting for resourceview elasticsearchnode-f18a8 to have 1 members ...
Still waiting for resourceview elasticsearchnode-f18a8 to have 1 members ...
Still waiting for resourceview elasticsearchnode-f18a8 to have 1 members ...
Still waiting for resourceview elasticsearchnode-f18a8 to have 1 members ...
Still waiting for resourceview elasticsearchnode-f18a8 to have 1 members ...
Still waiting for resourceview elasticsearchnode-f18a8 to have 1 members ...
Still waiting for resourceview elasticsearchnode-f18a8 to have 1 members ...
Still waiting for resourceview elasticsearchnode-f18a8 to have 1 members ...
Still waiting for resourceview elasticsearchnode-f18a8 to have 1 members ...
Still waiting for resourceview elasticsearchnode-f18a8 to have 1 members ...
Still waiting for resourceview elasticsearchnode-f18a8 to have 1 members ...
Still waiting for resourceview elasticsearchnode-f18a8 to have 1 members ...
Still waiting for resourceview elasticsearchnode-f18a8 to have 1 members ...
Still waiting for resourceview elasticsearchnode-f18a8 to have 1 members ...
Still waiting for resourceview elasticsearchnode-f18a8 to have 1 members ...
Still waiting for resourceview elasticsearchnode-f18a8 to have 1 members ...
Still waiting for resourceview elasticsearchnode-f18a8 to have 1 members ...
Still waiting for resourceview elasticsearchnode-f18a8 to have 1 members ...
Still waiting for resourceview elasticsearchnode-f18a8 to have 1 members ...
Still waiting for resourceview elasticsearchnode-f18a8 to have 1 members ...
Still waiting for resourceview elasticsearchnode-f18a8 to have 1 members ...
Still waiting for resourceview elasticsearchnode-f18a8 to have 1 members ...
Still waiting for resourceview elasticsearchnode-f18a8 to have 1 members ...
Still waiting for resourceview elasticsearchnode-f18a8 to have 1 members ...
Still waiting for resourceview elasticsearchnode-f18a8 to have 1 members ...
Still waiting for resourceview elasticsearchnode-f18a8 to have 1 members ...
```

There is [one relates SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27283139/your-cassandra-cluster-failed-to-deploy-replica-state-changed-to-permanently-fa) but the only unaccepted answer suggested it to be quota issue. At least that is not the case with me.

Any ideas? How should I approach to solve this problem?

Comment: It looks like there's a problem with the disk, /dev/disk/by-id/google-elasticsearch2-elasticsearch-aidd-data.  I suggest looking into that.  Is the disk formatted?  (Is it intended to be?)

Comment: Unable to find anything with that disk. Also I don't know much about how to check problem with any disk on GCE

Comment: not sure why you're getting this error but if you want to set up a hangout and try to diagnose it together I'm happy to help.  I wrote and maintain this solution so I have some knowledge of how it works.  We can then report back what we find here in case others have this issue. cpomeroy at google dot com.